How to keep a @FetchRequest’s predicate in sync with a View's @State when a view is recreated?
How can I keep a @FetchRequest's nsPredicate in sync with a View's @State when a view is recreated? When a view is recreated, @State variables are transiently initialized to a value set by the struct's initializers (either inline or in init), and then the persistent @State values replace the transient values. However when a view is recreated any @FetchRequest's nsPredicates are reinitialized, but then not replaced with the persistent state of the @FetchRequest.
Steps to reproduce

Add an xcdatamodel named TestCalendar2 with a single entity named Item that has a Date attribute named timestamp
Run the app, note that the List contains an item.
Tap "Recreate View" (to force recreation of the view), and note that the list is empty

MRE
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate.init(value: false))
    var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var counter: Int
    
    init(counter: Int) {
        print("**** init")
        self.counter = counter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.timestamp!, style: .date)
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            print("**** onAppear")
            let monthYear = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Date())
            items.nsPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
                NSPredicate(format: "timestamp >= %@", Calendar.current.date(from: monthYear)! as NSDate),
                NSPredicate(format: "timestamp <= %@", Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: Calendar.current.date(from: monthYear)!)! as NSDate)
            ])
        }
        .onReceive(items.publisher.collect()) { _ in
            print("**** onReceive")
            print(items)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestCalendarApp: App {
    @State var counter = 0
    
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Button("Recreate View") { print("****** Recreate View"); counter += 1 }
            ContentView(counter: counter)
            .onAppear() {
                addItem()
            }
        }
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
    }
    
    func addItem() {
        let item = Item(context: persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        item.timestamp = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        try? persistenceController.container.viewContext.save()
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCalendar2")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}

Output
**** init
ContentView: @self, @identity, _items, @16, @40 changed.
**** onReceive
FetchedResults<Item>(results: <__NSArray0 0x1e9c9d208>(

)
, controller: <_TtGC7SwiftUI15FetchControllerT_C13TestCalendar24ItemGVS_14FetchedResultsS2___: 0x600002616ac0>)
**** onAppear
ContentView: @40 changed.
**** onReceive
FetchedResults<Item>(results: <__NSArrayI 0x600002624d80>(
<Item: 0x600002148f50> (entity: Item; id: 0xa3d8f0f393928422 <x-coredata:///Item/p1>; data: {
    timestamp = "2024-04-07 04:00:00 +0000";
})
)
, controller: <_TtGC7SwiftUI15FetchControllerT_C13TestCalendar24ItemGVS_14FetchedResultsS2___: 0x600002616ac0>)

****** Recreate View
**** init
ContentView: @self changed.
**** onReceive
FetchedResults<Item>(results: <__NSArray0 0x1e9c9d208>(

)
, controller: <_TtGC7SwiftUI15FetchControllerT_C13TestCalendar24ItemGVS_14FetchedResultsS2___: 0x600002616ac0>)


Instead of using onAppear try using onChange for counter (or both)

Thank you, that is an interesting suggestion. Setting items.nsPredicate in onChange(of: counter) does fix the @FetchRequest, but oddly it doesn't trigger a call to body unless I also update state.

A simple way is to set the predicate at the top of body, then it will be updated whenever there is a change to a let passed in to the View or (as in your case) a @State declared inside the View, e.g.
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(value: false))
    var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    @State var predicate: NSPredicate = {
        let monthYear = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Date())
        return NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
            NSPredicate(format: "timestamp >= %@", Calendar.current.date(from: monthYear)! as NSDate),
            NSPredicate(format: "timestamp <= %@", Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: Calendar.current.date(from: monthYear)!)! as NSDate)
        ])
    }()

    func updatePredicate() {
        items.nsPredicate = predicate
    }

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        let _ = updatePredicate()
        ...


Thank you Mahal, this doesn't seem like a solution because any call to body forces a full requery of core data (I verified with -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1). To avoid that I would need to modifying state during view update which woudl cause undefined behavior

Please give the updated code a try!
